# Angular 2 If i mark a checkbox than mark checkall function, the selected checkbox doesn't continue marked

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to validate if checkbox is already marked when i apply the selectAll method, then continue marked instead of toggle it.

selecionarTodos() {

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.fornecedoresCheckbox.length; i++) {
if (this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].type == "checkbox") {
 if (!this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].checked)
  var fornecedorIds = parseInt(this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].value)
  this.checkboxChecked(fornecedorIds);

}
```

arrayCheckbox: Fornecedor[] = [];
  fornecedoresCheckbox = (document.getElementsByName("checkForn"));

//EXCLUIR CHECKBOX MARCADOS
  checkboxChecked(item) {

```
if (this.arrayCheckbox.find(x => x == item)) {

  this.arrayCheckbox.splice(this.arrayCheckbox.indexOf(item), 1)
  console.log(this.arrayCheckbox)

}
else {

  this.arrayCheckbox.push(item);
  console.log(this.arrayCheckbox)
  console.log(this.arrayCheckbox.length)

}
```

}

selecionarTodos() {

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.fornecedoresCheckbox.length; i++) {
if (this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].type == "checkbox") {
  var fornecedorIds = parseInt(this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].value)
  this.checkboxChecked(fornecedorIds);

}
```

}
  }

Answer (score 1):

While the way you have posted this question is quite hard to read, I believe the problem is that you are missing braces (`{}`) when you check if the checkbox is checked.

```
selecionarTodos() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fornecedoresCheckbox.length; i++) {
        if (this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (!this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].checked) {
                var fornecedorIds = parseInt(this.fornecedoresCheckbox[i].value)
                this.checkboxChecked(fornecedorIds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```